# Invoking publish inside a deliver handler rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

Suppose I have a queue 'Q1' and there is are multiple producers publishing to this queue and multiple consumers reading from this queue.

Now, each consumer will process the message from 'Q1' and again put it in some other queue say 'Q2'/'Q3'.

How should be the channels assocaited with it? I have created a single producer channel which will publish to any queue(Q1 and Q2/Q3) and multiple consumer channels. Is it ok to work with a single producer channel or there would be some synchronization issues?

Comment: Is the message unchanged in in it's existence from Q1 to Q2/Q3? What do you mean by 'associated channels' ? And what kind of sync issues do you mean? A producer is producing messages so...

Comment: Message is changed when pushed from Q1 to Q2/Q3. By 'associated channels', I mean the channel used  to publish or consume message. It is usually suggested that- applications should prefer using a Channel per thread instead of sharing the same Channel across multiple threads.But as Ia m using a single producer channel only, would there be any issues?

Comment: Technically no, there wouldn't. I've used C++ client lib and in there there's an simple example in which the client subscribes to queue, sends a message and then receives it, all using the same channel. https://github.com/alanxz/SimpleAmqpClient/blob/master/examples/simple_connect.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Generally the best practice is to have a channel for thread.

In case you use the same channel with more threads you should synchronize the access, there are client implementation that do it for you.

Now, if you use a single channel to publish to more queues is fine, but it should be serialized.

if you are looking for performance is better to have multi-threading publishers where each thread has his own channel.

The channel creation is very "cheap" in term of resource, so don't be afraid to use more channels.

The question is a bit generic, I hope it helps

Comment: My main concern is that I would be calling basicPublish method from inside handedelivery, to move the messages from Q1 to Q2/Q3. Say, I have 20 consumers attached to queue Q1 and each consumer has its own channel. Now inside the consumer I would be calling basicPublish to a 'producerChannel' which will be shared by all consumers.

Comment: Inside the delivery you can call a `publish` but you should use another channel. I found this post https://dzone.com/articles/rabbitmq-amqp-channel-best that it is very useful